# What is a word for this hand signal of refusal?

Tags: single-word-requests

When people decline something, sometimes they wave their hand back and forth as a gesture of refusal. What is a word for this?

Answer (score 4):

wave off-- to dismiss or refuse by waving the hand or arm: waved off his invitation to join the group. (http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Wave)

Comment: In 'Mercia it's mostly the middle finger except for Broadway.

Answer (score 0):

I think in Britain we would probably say 'waved away'. 'I tried to speak to her but she just waved me away'.